# Connect HP Deskjet 695Cci to RPi3

Tags: raspbian

How to connect HP Deskjet Printer 695Cci to RPi 3 with a serial to usb cable. HP has a driver. should it be installed first?Or isn't the driver already installed? I am new to Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After you install CUPS (look to my comment), load it up by using this url:

https://your IP address here:631/

Then, under the administration tab, click add printer. (This may tell you to go to the url https://192.168.1.16:631/admin/, do it. It may also warn you that your connection is unsafe, it's just doing its job; proceed to the site.)

Click add printer again, and proceed to enter your raspberry pi's user ID and password in the pop-up. Select your serial cord ID from the "local printers" section, and click continue. Check the options to make sure they are correct, and click continue again. Fill in the boxes with the printer's name, description, and location, and click continue, yet again. Select its make and model, so CUPS can install it's driver software, and click continue/add printer. Set the default options for your printer, and click set. After this, you should be set!

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that your serial communications are working first. If you can communicate with the printer, you should start researching setting up printing with CUPS. Under CUPS, you can configure the drivers assuming they exist for Linux. I always look for a printer definition (ppd) file and import that into CUPS.

Comment: @RRamachandran You said you were new to linux, so that may mean you don't know what CUPS is? If so, CUPS is a unix printing system (and a very old one too). Before you do anything, install CUPS with `sudo apt-get install cups` in your terminal emulator.